# How do you create a button that resets the form to the empty_value in symfony/twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form that I'm creating that has an `empty_value` for each option. I want a reset button that defaults to that option. The typical form reset button only resets to what the most recent POST request was. Is there a way to access to access that `empty_value`?

Comment: I can if there is a solution there

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar to @CarlosGranados and make an AJAX call, but I agree with him that its not really worth the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an optimal solution as it involves a page reload, but why don't you just have this reset button reload the page (load the url of the page with no post parameters). This would give you a form with all empty values.

Comment: True. I will default to this if I can't find anything better.

Comment: You could make an AJAX call to retrive the form data with empty values and then use javascript to reset all form fields to these values, but I am not sure it is worth the hassle